# Is it possible to get GSM cell name? Other infos?

Tags: gsm, at-command

Does the GSM operators hold this information of the Cell Name? Is it possible to get the Cell name as we usually do with Cell ID? Is it possible to ask for the tower's GPS position with an AT command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get a cell name using standard AT commands.  What sort of name do you mean, can you give an example?

For location information, have you tried AT+CMOLR, which is a standard AT command from 3GPP spec TS 27007?
Implementation of AT+CMOLR is optional, so it would not be surprising if it is not supported by the device.  If you know which device you are using, it might be better to check the manufacturer's proprietary AT command list.

(The 3GPP AT command specification is here: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm )

Answer (score 0):

Most of GSM carriers don't provide cellid locations (lat/lng).